# Injecting HLS stream into AWS Elemental MediaPackage from WOWZA

Tags: amazon-web-services, wowza, aws-elemental, aws-mediaservices, aws-mediapackage

I'm following https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-example-pushpublish-hls in order to inject an HLS stream from a Wowza into a AWS MediaPackage channel.

My PushPublishProfilesCustom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <PushPublishProfiles>
            <PushPublishProfile>
                    <Name>cupertino-file</Name>
                    <Protocol>HTTP</Protocol>
                    <BaseClass>com.mycompany.wms.example.pushpublish.protocol.cupertino.PushPublishHTTPCupertinoFileHandler</BaseClass>
                    <Implementation>
                            <Name>Cupertino File</Name>
                    </Implementation>
                    <HTTPConfiguration>
                    </HTTPConfiguration>
                    <Properties>
                    </Properties>
            </PushPublishProfile>
            <PushPublishProfile>
                    <Name>cupertino-http</Name>
                    <Protocol>HTTP</Protocol>
                    <BaseClass>com.mycompany.wms.example.pushpublish.protocol.cupertino.PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler</BaseClass>
                    <Implementation>
                            <Name>Cupertino HTTP</Name>
                    </Implementation>
                    <HTTPConfiguration>
                    </HTTPConfiguration>
                    <Properties>
                    </Properties>
            </PushPublishProfile>
    </PushPublishProfiles>
</Root>
```

My #APP_NAME#/PushPublishMap.txt (I'm adding EndOfLines to do reading easier)

```
MediaPackage={
              "entryName":"MediaPackage",
              "profile":"cupertino-http",
              "streamName":"MediaPackageStream",
              "destinationName":"MediaPackage0",
              "host":"xxxx.mediapackage.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/in/v2/xxxx/xxxx/channel", 
              "port":"443",
              "sendSSL":"true",
              "username":"xxxx,
              "password":"xxxx",
              "http.path":"hls"
}
```

When I'm sending data to my wowza ( rtsp://X.X.X.X:1935/#APP_NAME#/MediaPackage ) I start to see logs like this...

```
WARN    server  comment 2020-06-02  09:23:49    -   -   -   -   -   4325.922    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.outputSend([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) Found 79 segments to send
WARN    server  comment 2020-06-02  09:23:49    -   -   -   -   -   4325.922    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.outputSend([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) Found 76 segments to delete
ERROR   server  comment 2020-06-02  09:23:49    -   -   -   -   -   4325.934    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.outputSend([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) Send media segment. rendition: AUDIOVIDEO chunkId:77 uri:pdmekxw9/media_77.aac result:FAILURE
```

So, HLS Push Publishing is sending chunks... but without success

I have read https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-apple-hls-packetization-cupertinostreaming but I don't know what values I may change.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

EDIT: More logs

```
2020-06-02  14:32:39    UTC comment server  INFO    200 -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.createOutputItem([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) chunkCount:10, chunkStartIndex:201, lastChunkIndex:209   -   -   -22856.082  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2020-06-02  14:32:39    UTC comment server  INFO    200 -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.createOutputItem([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) playlistChunkCount:3, playlistChunkStartIndex:208    -   -   -   22856.082   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2020-06-02  14:32:39    UTC comment server  INFO    200 -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.createOutputItem([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) New chunk: chunkRendition:AUDIOVIDEO, chunkId:210, chunkIndex:2  -   --  22856.082   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2020-06-02  14:32:39    UTC comment server  INFO    200 -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.createOutputItem([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) Marking MediaSegmentModel: pcnod08j/media_207.aac for deletion   -   --  22856.083   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2020-06-02  14:32:39    UTC comment server  WARN    200 -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.outputSend([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) Found 32 segments to send  -   -   -   22856.083   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2020-06-02  14:32:39    UTC comment server  WARN    200 -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.outputSend([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) Found 29 segments to delete    -   -   -   22856.083   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2020-06-02  14:32:39    UTC comment server  ERROR   500 -   PushPublishHTTPCupertinoHTTPHandler.outputSend([MediaPackage] TV/_definst_/MediaPackage->MediaPackageStream) Send media segment. rendition: AUDIOVIDEO chunkId:208 uri:pcnod08j/media_208.aac result:FAILURE    -   -   -   22856.097
```

Comment: Hey, you figure this out by chance?